# Storyboard animation duration - how to obtain automatic computed value?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there a possiblity to obtain value od given Storyboard's duration when it is set to automatic? I need this exact value.
Or maybe there is a possibility to get notifcation when storyboard animation is starting?

Comment: What do you mean by storyboard starting? Maybe you want to say completed?

Comment: I need event to be fired just before animation start - wheen begin method is called.

Comment: You are talking about when Storyboard is inside a BeginStoryboard?

Comment: No i need an equivalent of Complete event but fired before storyboard is started.